# Retrieve contents of consecutive nested <div> with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

how to use `simple_html_dom` get each value `aaa`,`bbb`,`ccc`,`ddd` ? Thanks.

The HTML structure:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          aaa
        </div>
        bbb
      </div>
      ccc
    </div>
    ddd
  </div>
</body>

<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<body><div><div><div><div>aaa</div>bbb</div>ccc</div>ddd</div></body>');
echo $html->find('div', 0)->innertext.'<hr />'; //need output aaa
echo $html->find('div', 1)->innertext.'<hr />'; //need output bbb
echo $html->find('div', 2)->innertext.'<hr />'; //need output ccc
echo $html->find('div', 3)->innertext.'<hr />'; //need output ddd
?>
```

Comment: Surely you can think of a more descriptive question title.

Comment: ...why are you doing this in PHP?

Comment: @Matt Ball, I want get aaa <hr />bbb <hr />ccc <hr />ddd <hr /> via simple_html_dom from the original $html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If inntertext does not return nested tags then this should work:

```
echo $html->find('body', 0)->find('div', 0)->find('div',0)->find('div',0)->find('div',0)->innertext.'<hr />'; // prints aaa
echo $html->find('body', 0)->find('div', 0)->find('div',0)->find('div',0)->->innertext.'<hr />'; // prints bbb
echo $html->find('body', 0)->find('div', 0)->find('div',0)->innertext.'<hr />'; // prints ccc
echo $html->find('body', 0)->find('div', 0)->innertext.'<hr />'; // prints ddd
```

Comment: if you have control over the HTML itself then I would add ids to the divs so you can reference them specifically instead of recursively, then it will be easier to parse.